# Codename one media player pause and play issue

Tags: codenameone

I am facing an issue with playing video files in Cn1.
The video starts playing on play, pauses on pause, but does not resume back on play.
This also happens with the kitchen sink app.
Device: Motox

Further, if I am using the native player mode, the video play and pause works fine, but the video does not launch properly in full screen. It gets aligned to the left of the screen and the application is seen in the background in the rest of the screen.

The application is in landscape mode.

Answer (score 0):

This is a regression in Codename One's Android media player. It should be fixed for the next server update.

Comment: Great thanks ! Do you have any approximate time frame so that I can plan better. Also, if I pass the video URL (file based) to Display.getInsance().execute it says that the video cannot be played

Comment: Where is the video located in the file system? We suggest placing them in the app home dir. It should be sometime next week at the latest.

Comment: Thanks. The video is located under root/folder1/video/1.mp4 I cant place the videos in app home because the content is loaded separately and there will be atleast 100 videos

Comment: That doesn't sound like a valid on device folder. FileSystemStorage has a get app home folder URL. You should use that.

Comment: Hi, just wanted to check if this was included in the recent update. Thanks

Comment: Device builds or simulator?

Comment: This should be working now, if you have something that doesn't work we will need more details. E.g. does it work on the kitchen sink now? For full screen try using Display.execute